Can't get past "This sheet contains FactSet XML data" block on xlsx, when creating df
For a while now I've been trying to create a pandas dataframe out of a specific xlsx file that has FactSet XML data. I don't care about losing any of that.
If I try something as small as
df = pd.read_excel('Basecopy.xlsx', sheet_name=0, index_col=0)
df.to_excel('baseactivos2.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('baseactivos2.xlsx')
print(df2)

I already get this error:
Empty DataFrame Columns: [Unnamed: 0, This sheet contains FactSet XML data for use with this workbook's =FDS codes.  Modifying the worksheet's contents may damage the workbook's =FDS functionality.] Index: []
I'm not even trying to edit anything on the file.
I even resaved the file so that the only sheet I'm working with is entirely hardcoded.
How could I work this file to make it "dataframable"?

Which line causes the error? Why saving to excel with pandas again and not doing a plain file copy?

The error is triggered either when printing, copying to a new file, etc.
I need it to be a DF to compare with a DF I have from a SQL table, and later insert into the DB, I havr a working script already for that, but it doesn't work on this file.

That may not be an error but the name of column. Show us first sheet of that workbook that you are attempting to import. Is there a warning for FactSet? Try unhiding rows and columns.
